# Hide div for desktop and show it in phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I have a sticky div as my Topmenu. As standard it shows it all the time on all pages, but i want to hide it on desktop mode and show it on phone.

so here is what i have done:

```
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
    #sp-header-sticky-wrapper {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
        font-size: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0px !important;
        padding: 0;
        (optional) mso-hide: all;
        /* hide elements in Outlook 2007-2013 */
        (optional)
    }
    div#sp-header-sticky-wrapper.sticky-wrapper {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
        font-size: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0px !important;
        padding: 0;
        (optional) mso-hide: all;
        /* hide elements in Outlook 2007-2013 */
        (optional)
    }
}
```

and on the phone:

```
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    #sp-header-sticky-wrapper {
        display: block !important;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    div#sp-header-sticky-wrapper.sticky-wrapper {
        display: block !important;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

It works fine on the phone/tablet part, but when it comes to the desktop mode. there is a problem.

Everytime I click a link on my menu/other where, it shows the hidden div for like 0.x secs and then it hides it. Its like the white box is showing it and then gets hid after little bit of time, so the site always "moves" up, when I reload a page.

whats the solution? It may have a benefit that I should mention its a Joomla running page, so it may have something to do with the reading of the css files or?

Can i try with Javascript or is it impossible?

Comment: Try setting `display:none;` without media query, and with media query display it on mobile devices.

Comment: thanks for replying. the answer for my question was apparently that i had another div showing up(inside my sticky div) everytime i reloaded a page. and i had to hide that. and now it works like charm. thanks for replying guys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is the best article about this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Second of all: do not use visibility: visible/hidden, but display: none/block, works much better.

I would put main styles like this:

```
.desktop-div { display: block; }
.mobile-div { display: none; }

@media { .desktop-div { display: none; } .mobile-div { display: block; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a media query:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #div-name {
        display: none
    }
}
```